# c# printing how to handle cancel button?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, xps, cancel-button

Basically the application already can handle printing using `printPageeventArgs` and printed successfully. However the problem now is I'm not sure how to handle if user decided to cancel printing. Kindly refer to the below image:

[image]

Now instead of user clicking on "save" button, user click on "Cancel". May I know what method can I override?

**P/S:**
Please note that this popup only appear if your printer is **Microsoft XPS document Writer**. This is not the ordinary `printDialog.showDialog();`

Comment: Please post the code that pops up the dialog box.

Comment: @user3454439: Correct me if I'm wrong cause I think this "Save the file as" popup will appear by default only when the printer is Microsoft XPS document Writer

Comment: I don't understand the question: what do you want to do when the user cancel printing ?

Comment: @Thomas: This is for researching purpose. Let's say I want to print a HelloWorld?

Comment: @Thomas Kindly refer to my **P/S** thank you